# Return id from MyBatis @Insert for immutable object

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis, java-record

I have an immutable object Card:

```java
public record Card(int id, int deck_id, int count, String name) {}
```

And a mapper file with an insert statement:

```java
@Mapper
public interface DeckMapper {
    @Insert(value = "INSERT INTO deck (name) VALUES (#{name})")
    public int addDeck(Deck deck);
}
```

And a table in a MySQL 8 database:

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| name  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| id    | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I would like `addDeck` to return the id of the deck it creates. Normally, the way I would do this is either `@Options(useGeneratedKeys=true)`, or `@SelectKey`, but both solutions attempt to modify the underlying deck record, rather than just returning the id. This causes an exception because the object is immutable and therefore doesn't have a setter for id.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this behaviour. After modification, the deck object has its id and still is immutable. However, if you need the original deck object, you should make a copy of it before storing it in the database.

Comment: `@Insert` method returns the number of affected rows.
If `Deck` is a traditional class, MyBatis sets the generated key to the parameter object's property specified by `keyProperty` even if there is no setter method. If, however, `Deck` is a JEP-359 record, it's not possible to overwrite its field value (Java does not allow it even with reflection). So, if you want to get generated keys, you have to use a non-record class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We encountered the same problem. MyBatis could update the id of our immutable object, but we didn't want to mutate immutable objects. The caller of our method has no reason to expect the immutable object to be mutated. What we ended up doing was to use a wrapper class.

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
  Wrapper(T data){
    this.data = data;
  }

  T data;
  long id;
  // getters and setters
}
```

In our db code we had a method that was something like this:

```
public int insertAndReturnId<T>(string statement, T data)
{
  var wrappedData = Wrapper(data);
  sqlSessionTemplate.insert(statement, wrappedData);
  return wrappedData.id
}
```

We then used `useGeneratedKeys=true` as normal and accessed the parameters of whatever we inserted by using `wrapper.propertyA` in the SQL. We did not use annotations though, but a similar solution should be possible.